# A search box using pdo

Tags: php, pdo

i am trying to make a search box for my site using php pdo the following code saying :

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'

```
$input = str_replace(array('%','_'),'',$_POST['input']);
   if (!$input)
      {
         header('Location: index.php?action=null value');
            exit;
      }
        $query =('SELECT * FROM sales WHERE datetime LIKE :search OR datetime LIKE  :search'.$pages->get_limit());
          $stmt = $digital->prepare($query);
          $stmt->bindValue(':search', '%' . $input . '%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: There's two times `:search`. What's inside `$pages->get_limit()`? Also, why `PARAM_INT` if you put a string in there?

Comment: thanks i just fix it and it working

Comment: I am under the impression that you cannot re-use the same named placeholder in your sql for PDO. Try a different placeholder for the second but assign the same value in another bind statement